# DOM nodes leaking with knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dns, resource-leak

I have been seeing memory usage in IE8 and IE9 increase gradually over time with one of our web apps. After some investigation it appears to be related to the `foreach` binding in Knockout. I have compiled a simplified JSFiddle highlighting the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfbbprkh/1/

In the real app the model is updated from the back-end with the status being overwritten each time. If you flip the checkbox

Running this in Chrome you can see the DOM usage creep up gradually before the Garbage Collector kicks in, in IE8 and IE9 this doesn't happen the DOM usage keeps rising and rising. I've also run a slight variation on this through sIEve and that also highlights the issue.

In the fiddle you can disable the `foreach` binding by using the checkbox and when using the profiling tools in Chrome you'll see the DOM usage remain steady hence why I suspect this is related to the `foreach` binding and the way that it adds and removes the DOM elements. I'm guessing that the elements have some event handler still attached to them which is why they aren't cleaned up properly.

I have also tried replacing the 'nested' `foreach` with a template (don't know how to do this in fiddle) but it still exhibits the same issue.

So the question is - what am I doing wrong or is this a genuine bug with Knockout?

Notes:

- The timestamps are there to show something's happening (we do have similar ones in the real app)
- We have to support at least IE8 which in turn means JQuery 1.9x

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't even work?  I added ko and jQuery references for you so please update your answer - http://jsfiddle.net/jfbbprkh/1/

Comment: @PWKad apologies about that, I did check it worked when I submitted the link so don't know what went wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I find that if you use nested models for this sort of thing memory leaks become less of an issue. This way, 'Status' is not set to an observable, just the properties within 'Status'.

Try something like

```
var status = {
    Timestamp: ko.observable(),
    Rows: ko.observableArray([]),
    Update: function (updateValues) {
        status.Timestamp(updateValues.Timestamp);
        status.Rows(updateValues.Rows)
    }
}

var model = {
    EnableStatus: ko.observable(true),
    Timestamp: ko.observable(),
    Status: status,

    Update: function () {
        model.Timestamp(new Date());
        model.Status.Update({Timestamp: new Date(),
            Rows: [{
                Name: "Row #0",
                Value: Math.random()
            }, {
                Name: "Row #1",
                Value: Math.random()
            }, {
                Name: "Row #2",
                Value: Math.random()
            }]})
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(model, $("#wrapper")[0]);
    setInterval(model.Update, 1000);
});
```

Fiddle here >>> http://jsfiddle.net/uv0ga3gn/

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll give it a go, I should have perhaps have said that the models are being updated by the ko.mapping plugin. The model provided is actually one of many included in the "top-level" model in the real app so will require a little bit of re-thinking to implement completely.

Comment: Unfortunately still seems to be leaking DOM nodes in both Chrome and IE with the simple example.